# Sharepoint 2010 Calendar Overaly with public calendar in Exchange 2010

Tags: calendar, exchange-server

I figured out the trust relationship between SharePoint 2010 and Exchange 2010. Now when I do a calendar overlay to a public calendar it not only displays the public calendar items but also all of calendar items in my personal calendar. I only want it to display the public calendar items for users and not their items. I am concerned that something is not configured properly as I cannot find anyone posting the same issue and I would assume that this would be a common request.

Comment: Is your "public" calendar and exchange calendar?  If so, would you mind "answering" this question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/system-xml-xmlexception-when-using-sharepoint-exchange-calendar-overlay/17030#17030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to Exchange, SharePoint will by default connect to the authenticated users calendar.  I don't think there is a way to change this behavior OOTB.