# System.Xml.XmlException when using SharePoint Exchange Calendar Overlay

Tags: 2010, calendar

My organization wants to overlay a Shared Calendar onto a SharePoint calendar.  I've been able to overlay my outlook calendar onto the calendar using the following configuration URLs in the calendar overlay.

OWA: http://exchange/owa
EWS: http://exchange/ews

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232199%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) suggests I can configure an OWA path directly to my calendar using the following URL:
https://exchange/owa/?cmd=contents&module=Publicfolders&f=%2fShared%20Calendar

Unfortunately, this throws an exception, logged in the ULS:

> System.Xml.XmlException: '=' is an unexpected token. The expected
>   token is ';'. Line 1, position 249.    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)     at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean
>   isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributeValueSlow(Int32 curPos,
>   Char quoteChar, NodeData attr)     at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()     at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()     at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()     at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)     at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.ParsePartialContent(XmlNode parentNode, String
>   innerxmltext, XmlNodeType nt)     at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadInnerXmlElement(XmlElement node, String
>   innerxmltext)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPView.SetInnerXmlForNode(String nodeName, String
>   xml)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Calendar.CalendarAccessorManagerImpl.SaveAccessors()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AggregationCustomizePage.BtnOk_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

My research suggests that we are trying to do isn't possible.  I've seen no indication that folks have been able to successfully overlay a calendar other than the current user's calendar.

Has anyone been able to resolve the occurance of the XmlException?

Answer (score 1):

Your pulling infomraiton on creating a URL that is rendered via the Exchange web interface.

However, you are appear to still be correct.  When you add an exchange calendar URL you enter the webmail URL and the Exchange Web Services URL.  It appears SharePoint will only accept the webmail root, and passes in the current signed in user.  It doesn't appear out of the box that there is a way to overlay another user calendar.

You would have to find a way to intercept the service request and replace the current user with the 'exchange shared calendar user'.

Comment: How do I specify a name when my only configuration options are the OWA and EWS URLs?

Comment: Specified in the overlay options of the calendar.  Here is a link with screen shots, as well as how to do it programmaticly.

Comment: I don't see a link?

Comment: Sorry.  http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2011/06/programmatically-setting-sharepoint-2010-calendar-overlays/

Comment: That documents a SharePoint overlay.  Exchange overlays are configured differently.

Comment: He added the exchange portion to his Powershell script /code he covers.  It is not that different.  However I have made edited the answer.